# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin(x-x^2))^2 - x^2 + 2x^3}{\sin^{4}(2x)}$ using Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin(x-x^2))^2 - x^2 + 2x^3}{\sin^{4}(2x)}$$ using Taylor series.

Is there any reasonable cancellation that should be happening here? Using the Taylor series for $\sin$ I have gotten that $$\frac{(\sin(x-x^2))^2 - x^2 + 2x^3}{\sin^{4}(2x)}=\frac{\left((x-x^2) - \frac{(x-x^2)^3}{3!}+ \frac{(x-x^2)^5}{5!} - \dots \right)^2-x^2+2x^3}{\left(2x-\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}+ \frac{(2x)^5}{5!}- \dots\right)^4}$$

but this is really awful looking expression and there isn't really any way to simplify these squares and fourth powers that we got.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is a fourth power, so a total order of four for the $x$ will suffice.

$$\sin^2(x-x^2) \approx x^2-2 x^3+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

$$\sin^4(2x) \approx 16 x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Thence

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{x^2-2 x^3+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^5\right) - x^2 + 2x^3}{16 x^4+O\left(x^5\right)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\frac{2}{3}x^4}{16x^4} = \dfrac{1}{24}$$

Comment: This is better. To clarify for the OP, the idea is to expand only the parts of the power that will result in $x^4$ or lower order terms.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use trigonometry, you could use the $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos2x}{2}$, and then use the Taylor series for $\cos$. I'm not sure if there is a direct formula to reduce $\sin^4$. One way would be to treat it first as $(\sin^2)^2$, expand the simple algebra, and substitute the $\cos^2$ that appears with $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1 + \cos2x}{2}$. After reducing all the $\sin$ and $\cos$ to their first powers, then apply Taylor series. This may also get messy, but hopefully less.

Answer (score 0):

Numerator $= \sin^2(x-x^2) - (x-x^2)^2+x^4$

Let $\theta = x-x^2$. Now $\sin^2 \theta - \theta^2 = \left(\sin \theta - \theta \right)\left(\sin \theta + \theta \right) \approx -\dfrac{\theta^3}{6} \left(2 \theta)\right)=-\dfrac{\theta^4}{3}$

$=-\dfrac{(x-x^2)^4}{3}$

Hence Numerator $\approx \dfrac{2x^4}{3} + O(x^5)$ while Denominator $\approx 16x^4+O(x^5)$ and hence limit is $\dfrac{1}{24}$